# Using AWK or SED, add line with semicolon in it before regexp

Tags: awk, sed

Groups of lines in file:

```
Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Vendor      datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Feature     datadata
```

The first group of lines is fine. In the second group, I need to add a line for `vendor`. For the third group, I need to add two lines for `term` and `vendor`. I've searched for similar questions, but can't find the right solution. These are headers for data that follows to the right on the same line, so I can't use just a simple find and replace.

Result wanted:

```
Types      datadata
Term       datadata
Vendor     datadata
Feature    datadata

Types      datadata
Term       datadata
;
Feature    datadata

Types      datadata
;
;
Feature    datadata
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be:

```
Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Vendor      datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Feature     datadata
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{arr["Types"]=arr["Term"]=arr["Vendor"]=arr["Feature"]=";"}
(NF>=1){arr[$1]=$0}
(NF<1){print arr["Types"];print arr["Term"];print arr["Vendor"];print arr["Feature"];print $0;
arr["Types"]=arr["Term"]=arr["Vendor"]=arr["Feature"]=";"}
END{print arr["Types"];print arr["Term"];print arr["Vendor"];print arr["Feature"]}' file.txt
```

output

```
Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Vendor      datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Term        datadata
;
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
;
;
Feature     datadata
```

Explanation: In `BEGIN` I create `arr` with `Types`, `Term`, `Vendor`, `Feature` all `;`. For every line with data I set corresponding `arr` value to that line. For every line without data I print content `arr` in required order, that line without data and again set everything in `arr` to `;`. In `END` I print `arr` same way as for line without data - this is required if and only if your data last line is not empty.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: These are all really good options! I am working with all three to see how they go and operate within my longer script. I'll pick one as the answer, but any of these three versions could be used.

Answer (score 1):

I created a file, `script.awk`, containing this code:

```
function print_key(key)
{
    if (key in saved)
        print saved[key]
    else
        print ";"
}
function process_data()
{
    if (nsaved > 0)
    {
        print_key("Types")
        print_key("Term")
        print_key("Vendor")
        print_key("Feature")
        print ""
    }
    delete saved
    nsaved = 0
}
NF > 0  { saved[$1] = $0; nsaved++ }
NF == 0 { process_data() }
END     { process_data() }
```

I ran it on your sample data (contained in a file called `data`):

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Vendor      datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Term        datadata
;
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
;
;
Feature     datadata

$
```

What the script does is:

1. Define a function that takes one argument, `key`.  If that key is present in the array `saved`, it is printed; if not, then a semicolon is printed on a line on its own.
2. Define a function that looks to see if there is any data to be printed, and if so, prints each of the keys `"Types"`, `"Term"`, `"Vendor"` and `"Feature"`, and then an empty line.  It also zaps the saved data, deleting the array `saved` and setting `nsaved` back to zero.
3. When the number of fields is greater than 0, the line is non-empty.  The first field is used as a key to the `saved` array and saves the whole line for later printing.
4. When the number of fields is 0, the line is empty, and the previous block of data is processed.
5. At the end of the input, the previous block of data is processed.  If there was a blank line at the end of the file, there'll be no data to be processed.

Comment: Nice script! FWIW I'd have been tempted to use `function val(key) { if (key in saved) return saved[key]; else return ";" }` and `print val("Types")` just so that determining the value wasn't coupled to doing something with the value (i.e. printing it) and so just 1 function does all of the printing. But nbd either way.

Comment: That’s a reasonable change, @EdMorton — I might even make it if I were planning to use the script seriously.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ tag2val[$1] = $0 }
!NF { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt(   n,i,tag,tags) {
    n = split("Types Term Vendor Feature",tags)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        tag = tags[i]
        print (tag in tag2val ? tag2val[tag] : ";")
    }
    print ""
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Types       datadata
Term        datadata
Vendor      datadata
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
Term        datadata
;
Feature     datadata

Types       datadata
;
;
Feature     datadata
```